# Gimp won't launch

Tags: gimp

When I start Gimp from the terminal it won't launch. I get the following error message:

```
(gimp:17589): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used
resources file at `/home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but
the parser failed: Failed to open file
'/home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Permission denied.
```

Not sure how to set the permissions for this.

Comment: Issue this command `getfacl /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` and update question with this info

Comment: I issued the command:

Comment: I issued the command getfacl /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel but am unsure about what to do next.

Comment: Man, please update question with output of that command.  Next, I will think that we can do with it.

Comment: Sorry. getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::---
other::---

Comment: see, my answer. Believe it will help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23359/discussion-between-richard-lott-and-user3417815).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue this command to fix GIMP:

```
sudo chown richard:richard /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Try to run GIMP or post me result.

EDIT:

Revert it back in case of fail:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

and try to set new permissions

```
sudo chmod 700 /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

UPDATE:

Setting `/home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` owner to `richard:richard` and `0600` permission together with removing old GIMP configs probably solved problem.

Comment: I issued the command and tried to run GIMP but it still doesn't launch. It starts and shows up in the launcher but doesn't open. I didn't get any error messages at all.

Comment: updated answer, please issue one more time and let me know results.

Comment: Same result. It starts to load and shows up in the launcher but does not open.

Comment: no error messages at all.

Comment: ok, please try to rename this file. sudo mv /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.backup and run gimp one more time. Please let me know results

Comment: I ran the command sudo mv /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.backup and re-started gimp but got the same results as before.

Comment: And one more time please issue `sudo chown richard:richard 0600 /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.backup && sudo mv /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.backup /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` and please try to run GIMP again. If it didn't helped please post this file content.

Comment: Please also post your used ubuntu version and GIMP version. Maybe there is a bug that should or was being reported.

Comment: I have to leave for a few hours. I will follow up when I get back. Sorry I am such a beginner and thanks for your help!!!

Comment: When I issue the above commands i get the following error messages: chown: cannot access ‘0600’: No such file or directory. I am running ubuntu 14.04 and gimp 2.8

Comment: Sorry, it should be `sudo chown richard:richard /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.backup && sudo mv /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.backup /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel && sudo chmod 600 /home/richard/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23371/discussion-between-user3417815-and-richard-lott).

Comment: I am happy to but how do I do that?

Comment: Press accept symbol (like big V) under my answer score at the left of the "Try to run GIMP or post me result." words

Comment: Done. Once again I can't thank you enough for your time and help!